# Changing component from another screen

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenhos 2 forms, where one is usercontrol and one is a normal window. so I load that usercontrol into my window. What I would like to do is to change a value in my window when I click on a usercontrol button.

window [user control]

when I click on a user control button eg "change color window" I change the background color of my window.

how is this possible?

will it be that if I create a global class and put an object of type windows I will be able to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. There are numerous ways you can achieve this. I will list the easy ones :

**Create an Event in the `UserControl`, Raise it and listen to it**

Inside your `UserControl`, create a `public` event :

**> UserControl.Cs**

```
public Event EventHandler MyEvent;
///raise the event
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 MyEvent(this , e);
}
```

**> Wndows.Cs**

```
Usercontrol1.MyEvent += new System.EventHandler(this.MyMethod);

pirvate void MyMethod
{
 ////do stuff here 
}
```

**Use `GetWindow` method**

You can simply make use of `GetWindow` method :

```
  private void btn_Click()
  {
  Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
  ///code here
  }
```

**Use VisualTreeHelper**

Here's a function you can use to find the parent of a control. This is very useful because it will not only let you get the window but any parent of the child such as `StackPanel`,`Grid` etc..

```
 public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child)where T : DependencyObject
{
DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
if (parentObject == null)
    return null;
T parent = parentObject as T;
if (parent != null)
    return parent;
else
    return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
}

////Call it like this :

 var parent = FindParent<Window>(this);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could get a reference to the parent window from a `UserControl` using the `Window.GetWindow` method once the `UserControl` has been loaded:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        if (parentWindow != null)
            parentWindow.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why check if parentWindow is null or not ?

Comment: Because it's a best practice to always check whether a reference is valid to avoid NullReferenceExceptions :) You don't need to to this here though unless you are casting parentWindow to some specific Window class that you intend to set some property or call some method on.

Comment: Okay, I understand now :) Argh....I was the first one who was about to answer but there's something called `INTERNET DROPPED` occurred ! :( lol